# Change TabPageIndicator footer and text colors (ViewPagerIndicator)

Tags: android

This is driving me insane: I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the footer and text colors of my TabPageIndicator (from Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator). I looked at the source code for the sample ViewPagerIndicator app and I can't find where the code differs for the "Default" and the "Styled" samples. The Default has the default blue footer and white text, whereas the Styled sample has a red footer and uses a gray font.

I know it's possible, but I can't find out how to do it!! Any help is tremendously appreciated. :)

Comment: can you give us the link of  the source code for the sample ViewPagerIndicator app?

Comment: @haythemsouissi: here you are: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it's different from Manifest definition for theme:

For default tab:

```
<activity
            android:name=".SampleTabsDefault"
            android:label="Tabs/Default"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults">
```

And styled tab:

```
<activity
            android:name=".SampleTabsStyled"
            android:label="Tabs/Styled"
            android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators">
```

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't look hard enough at the sample. It seems the way he changed the footer color was to supply different Drawable images to use as the footer. I was hoping it would be as simple as adding a line of XML, but apparently I'm going to have to open up Photoshop and remake the tiles using my own color. Too bad; I wish he (Jake Wharton) made it use Colors instead of images. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: How to change the text color?

Comment: @EverythingTech96 hey how did u manage to change the drawable images where are they located ... plz guide me .. its makin me mad.. all i have found is vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle .. :S

Comment: @baboo The drawable images are in Android-ViewPagerIndicator/res/drawable-*. If you need more info I suggest you view the source code for the sample application for ViewPagerIndicator. It's been so long since I did this and I haven't worked on the app I used this for in a while. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @Dhasneem In your custom style for vpiTabPageInidcatorStyle, define  android:textColor. If you need more info I suggest you look in styles.xml for the sample ViewPager application.

Comment: thanks man worked it out :D ... changed the 9patch images and added in custom style as background of vpiTabPageInidcatorStyle ...

Comment: @anticafe so that we can't use it in Fragment  ah?

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct answer is to add the following style to your style.xml file (this contains elements telling VPI how to show).  Something like this:

```
<style name="Widget.MyTitlepageIndicator">
    <item name="footerColor">#ff99cc33</item>
    <item name="footerIndicatorStyle">underline</item>
    <item name="footerIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
    <item name="footerLineHeight">1.5dp</item>
    <item name="footerPadding">6dp</item>
    <item name="selectedColor">#ffffffff</item>
</style>
```

Then, in the layout.xml file, where you define your VPI, you just tell it about the style you created, like this:

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/history_vp_ind"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MyTitlepageIndicator" />
```

Comment: Your example pertains to `TitlePageIndicator` whereas the original question was referring to `TabPageIndicator`.

Answer (score 1):

To do it programmatically, modify the TabPageIndicator and add the following method:

```
public void setTextColor(int color) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = mTabLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof TextView)
            ((TextView) child).setTextColor(color);
    }
}
```

Then just use the method to change the text color of the views in the indicator. For example

```
setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF)
```

would be white.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the default background of **TabPageIndicator** in 2 ways

**1.** you can change the **background** in the XML

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0c445c" />
```

**2.** Replace the constructor in **TabPageIndicator.java** class in the **viewpager library**

```
public TabPageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        mTabLayout = new IcsLinearLayout(context, R.attr.vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle);
        mTabLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0c445c"));
        addView(mTabLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, MATCH_PARENT));
    }
```

Hope this HELP