# Styling a TabPageIndicatior

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to style `TabPageIndicatior` of `ViewPagerIndicator` in XML. So far I have reached this [based on an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167416/change-tabpageindicator-footer-and-text-colors-viewpagerindicator):

```
<style name="Widget.MyTitlepageIndicator">
        <item name="android:background">@color/indicator_background_grey</item>
        <item name="footerColor">@color/indicator_footer_orange</item>
        <item name="footerIndicatorStyle">underline</item>
        <item name="footerIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
        <item name="footerLineHeight">3dp</item>
        <item name="footerPadding">0dp</item>
        <item name="selectedColor">@color/indicator_footer_orange</
</style>
```

However, this does not get the desired result. The result I am looking for [is this](http://myapptemplates.com/product/event-android-app-template). I am trying to get a page indicator similar to that.

[image]

What changes need to be made to get that look?

Comment: do you mean like the vertical ..?

Comment: Can you show me that image only 
there is lot of image in site :)

Comment: how about using https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: @saleeh93 That seems to be the solution for now. For now atleast.

Comment: Do you want to customize that Or the one with system

Comment: @saleeh93 `PagerSlidingTabStrip` has the properties exposed to be customized. I was talking about `ViewPagerIndicator`. Need to learn how to customize that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip
they have Customization options

## Customization

To not just look like another Play Store styled app, go and adjust these values to match
your brand:

- `pstsIndicatorColor` Color of the sliding indicator
- `pstsUnderlineColor` Color of the full-width line on the bottom of the view
- `pstsDividerColor` Color of the dividers between tabs
- `pstsIndicatorHeight`Height of the sliding indicator
- `pstsUnderlineHeight` Height of the full-width line on the bottom of the view
- `pstsDividerPadding` Top and bottom padding of the dividers
- `pstsTabPaddingLeftRight` Left and right padding of each tab
- `pstsScrollOffset` Scroll offset of the selected tab
- `pstsTabBackground` Background drawable of each tab, should be a StateListDrawable
- `pstsShouldExpand` If set to true, each tab is given the same weight, default false
- `pstsTextAllCaps` If true, all tab titles will be upper case, default true

*All attributes have their respective getters and setters to change them at runtime*

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs_diagonal"
        app:pstsDividerColor="#00000000"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FF33B5E6"
        app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dip"
        app:pstsUnderlineColor="#FF33B5E6" />
```

Comment: A simple example using these properties would be great ! :)

Comment: Check the updated answer :)
You can use all properties Form run Time Or Also In Xml

Comment: Here's a more complete answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871005/error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix-on-pagerslidingtabstrip